# Noexcept specifier: why no compile time checks?

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

I'm studying the `noexcept` specifier and I am wondering about the reason behind some of its design decision. In particular, the reason why it doesn't make the same compile time checks as, for example, the `constexpr` specifier. I will explain this assertion later on.

This is the code I am testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

void g()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("EXCEPT");
}

void f() noexcept
{
    g();
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        f();
    }
    catch(const std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught this: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This version of the code compiles but crashes, because (if I understand it well) the with the `noexcept` specifier the compiler has just "trusted me" and has made optimization that won't allow the code at runtime to handle any exception, despite the `try`/`catch` block.

What I do not understand is: why the compiler does not check a simple thing like the signature of `g()`? `g()` has not been declared `noexcept`, so without going on expensive checking if it really throws or not, the code should be just be considered *wrong*, because `g()` is implicitly `noexcept(false)`. In which case is this useful?

To work as I personally expected it to work, I have to change the signature of `f()` like this:

```
void f() noexcept(noexcept(g()))
{
    g();
}
```

Now, the `noexcept` specifier on `f()` declaration is applyied only if it appears in `g()` declaration as well. At runtime, the exception is perfectly handled. Why is this not the default? If `f()` calls a lot of functions, doing the `noexcept(noexcept(g()))` for every called function by hand is a maintenance hell.

I was quoting the `constexpr` specifier because it actually makes the compiler check that all those functions called by the `constexpr` function are themselves declared as `constexpr`. So, I think the reason why `noexcept` does not do the same has anything to do with the compilation time.

**Summing the question up:** why the compiler does not check that the functions called by a `noexcept` function are themselves declared as `noexcept`?